# Как получить найти элемент-инъекцию на странице используя puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Есть расширение браузера, которое модифицирует страницу вставляет в нее свой html код, я получаю html код проверяемой страницы, но в него не попадает html код-инъекция из расширения, хотя если прогонять в браузере проверку то инъекция есть.

т.е. после рендеринга страницы расширение интегрирует внутрь страницы блок:

```
<div><div class="notification"><div class="notification__close"></div> <div class="notification__logo"></div> <div class="notification__title">
  </div> <div class="notification__cta">
    Activate
  </div></div> <!----></div>
```

При попытке выловить этот блок, puppeteer его не находит:

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      ignoreDefaultArgs: true,
      args: [
        `--load-extension=${path.join(dir, '/extension')},`
      ]
    });
let page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https:/site.url', {waitUntil : 'networkidle2' });
await page.waitForSelector('.notification__cta');
await page.click('.notification__cta');
```

Получаю отвал по таймауту при попытке найти элемент:
: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

Если посмотреть html который хранится в page, то туда блок notification не попадает...
Возможно будут у кого-то идеи как я могу папетиром отследить html-инъекции и манипулировать ими?

Answer (score 1):

Элемент попадает в shadow dom, решением стал пакет query-selector-shadow-dom (https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-selector-shadow-dom)